# how to allow access to port on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am trying to connect to my development port `port 3000` on aws but it is not working. I have currently configured my domain with the instance and it is working fine but I cannot access port 3000 and get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

The security group setting is as below

[image]

As you can see, I have opened up my mongo port `27017` and `3000` which is my node server port

[image]

As you can see here, it is listening at `port 3000`. I set it to print out the exact port that is being listened.

When I go `netstat -natlp` the following shows

[image]

port 3000 is currently listening.

I have followed all the instructions and suggestions but it is still not working for a weird reason. The server I use is Asia(Seoul) server.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The server has a public IPv4 or is there a reverse proxy server before? And do you use the IP or DNS to access your serivce, does the VM has some local FW activated - did you tried to access the service from another instance over curl / wget? Which ami image do you use?

Comment: just for a trial , try enabling all access and see if it works. At least it will help u go in the right direction.

Comment: Are you behind a (corporate?) firewall that does not allow outbound port 3000?

Comment: @proton2b it has public IPv4 and I am forwarding my port 3000 to port 80. But even before that I couldn't access it by attempting at the port directly

Comment: @Jocket I have enabled all access and result is the same

Comment: @jarmod no just an individual user. I have not set up any additional firewall other than what may already been set up as a default

Comment: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` means you *can* access the instance, but the service is not sending a response body.  You'd see Connection refused or Connection times out if you couldn't connect.  Test your node server with a proper tool, like `curl` with the `-v` option and you will get *far* better diagnostics.

Comment: Is the public subnet connected to a Internet Gateway?

Comment: @strongjz I guess it is because before I forward my port 3000 to port 80, I could see the apache welcome message when I accessed it